# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: getUserDataForUsername(): Argument #1 ($username) must be of type string, null given

Tags: php

I`m trying to build a login form with E-Mail and Minecraftname. I want to check if

1. there`s an E-Mail
2. there`s an Minecrafname
3. the Minecraftname is in our database
   If all 3 are the case the next step would take part. (send E-Mail etc.)

```
function getUserDataForUsername(string $username): array
{
     $sql = "SELECT unique_id FROM kype.cloud_players WHERE username=:username";

     $statement = getDB()->prepare($sql);
     if (false === $statement) {
         return [];
     }
     $statement->execute([
         ':username' => $username
     ]);
     if (0 === $statement->rowCount()) {
         return [];
     }
     $row = $statement->fetch();
     return $row;
}
```

```
if (strpos($route, '/login') !== false) {
    $isPost = strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'POST';
    $username = "";
    $mcname = "";
    $errors = [];
    $hasErrors = false;
    if ($isPost) {

        $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
        $mcname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

        if (false === (bool) $username) {
            $errors[] = "E-Mail is empty";
        }
        if (false === (bool) $mcname) {
            $errors[] = "Minecraftname is empty";
        }
        $userData = getUserDataForUsername($username);
        if ((bool) $username && 0 === count($userData)) {
            $errors[] = "test";
        }
        if (
            (bool) $mcname &&
            isset($userData['mcname']) &&
            false === password_verify($mcname,
                $userData['mcname'])
        ) {
            $errors[] = "This player hasn`t been on the server yet";
        }
        if (0 === count($errors)) {
            $_SESSION['userID'] = (int) $userData['id'];
        }

    }
    $hasErrors = count($errors) > 0;


    require __DIR__ . '/templates/login.php';
    exit();
}
```

I expected one of my error messages but it gave me following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: getUserDataForUsername(): Argument #1 ($username) must be of type string, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\kypemc\shop\routes.php on line 65 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\kypemc\shop\functions\user.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\kypemc\shop\routes.php(65): getUserDataForUsername(NULL) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\kypemc\shop\includes.php(6): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\kypemc\shop\index.php(7): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\kypemc\shop\functions\user.php on line 16
```

Comment: Why are you testing if $usename and $mcname is false?

Comment: If its false its empty. Both of them are required. @JasonK

Comment: You are using === in the ff statement. It is already testing by type so you do not need to cast the (bool).  The call to getUserDataForUsername() is failing because the username is a type of bool not a string. When empty.

Comment: `if (false === (bool) $mcname)` - what should that do? Why not check **properly** whether the variable is empty, for example by comparing it to an empty string?